# Introducir datos en tabla phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando introducir datos en una tabla en phpmyadmin. La cuestión es que al realizar la consulta de insertar no me introduce los datos correspondientes al libro con el id en cuestión. Si quiero declarar la variable como string inicialmente vacía, como sería?

```
`<?php

       include "../includes/conexionBD.php"; 


            if (isset($_GET["operacion"]) && $_GET["operacion"]=="Cesta" ) /
            {
                    $query ="INSERT INTO cesta(id_cesta,id,titulo, precio,portada) VALUES (0, " . $_GET["idAnadir"] . ", 0, 0,1);";

                    $resultado = mysqli_query( $enlaceBD, $query); //almacena conexion y consulta                   


             }


       ?>
```

$query = "SELECT * FROM libros"; //consulta que muestre todos los libros de la base de datos
                           $resultado = mysqli_query( $enlaceBD, $query); //almacena conexion y consulta

```
                       while ($datos = $resultado ->fetch_assoc()) {

                       }
                    echo "<div class='libro'>






 <a class='btnComprar' href='view/libros.php?operacion=Cesta&idAnadir=" .  $nuevoLibro->getId() . "'>COMPRAR</a>
   </div>";



?>`
```